# Defining constants inside a script?

Tags: broken-code

At the beginning of my script, I define a constant E by writing E:=2u+2uv, but then at the end of the script after running the final command, the result comes out with the form K/(2u+2uv). My question is simple: how do I make Mathematica recognise that the result should be in the form K/E?

Comment: Without knowing any details, `E` is a built-in symbol.

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you do not want 2u+2uv to be substituted for E, why are you defining E:=2u+2uv

Comment: 1) Do you mean `2*u + 2*u*v` or  `2*u + 2*uv`? 2) Also, `E := 2u+2uv` means `E` gets replaced with 2*u + 2*uv`, not the other way around. Since `E` is a protected, built-in symbol,  didn't you get an error message?

Comment: I mean 2u(1+v), which is 2u+2uv. And I've tried changing the symbol to a lower case e to avoid the confusion with the built-in E, but I get some strange error:

    Tag Plus in 2u+2uv is protected

Comment: What you are trying to do is achieved through `Simplify` and similar commands, and not through defining a value for `e`. For instance, see the following: `Simplify[k/(2 u + 2 u v), e == 2 u (1 + v)]` returns `k/e`, which I think is what you want. Note also the important fact that `uv` is DIFFERENT from `u v` (notice the space, which is interpreted as multiplication). The first is a single variable named $uv$, the second is the product of $u$ by $v$. If you want to be extra explicit, you can also use `*` to indicate multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take the expression that you have at the end of the script

```
K/(2 u + 2 u  v)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and look at it using `FullForm`. Looking at expressions using `FullForm` is a good way to figure out how to perform replacements or substitutions.

```
FullForm[K/(2 u + 2 u  v)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We will take the portion enclosed by `Power` and attempt to replace it (`/.` is a shortcut for `ReplaceAll`) with the symbol `e`.

```
K/(2 u + 2 u  v) /. Plus[Times[2, u], Times[2, u, v]] -> e

(* K/e *)
```

This produces the desired result.

So you can place this at the end of your script.

If you are still struggling, kindly place your actual code in the question and you will doubtless get an answer that fits your needs.